# How can I specify Google map with driving direction in jQuery mobile

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova, dictionary

I have done a Google Maps based application in PhoneGap (jQuery mobile). The task is to connect the starting and finishing locations. I am able to link these points by using marker and polyline technique. I can get only a straight line which is connecting both. But, I want to link the two locations via the driving path between these two locations. Like the marked area from the map below. Please help me on this.

I have my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/rajmathan/NALA5/

**Update:** I also find a code in ActionScript with the same functionality.But,I do not know how to use this in mycode

`var directionOptions:DirectionsOptions = new DirectionsOptions({language: 'en',countryCode: 'US,DE',travelMode: DirectionsOptions.TRAVEL_MODE_DRIVING});`

[image: atlanda]

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
});

function onSuccess(position) {
  var vLatitude = 18.9750;
  var vLongitude = 72.8258;
  var cur_lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var cur_lng = position.coords.longitude;
  var start = cur_lat+","+cur_lng;
  var end = vLatitude+","+vLongitude;
  var url = 'https://maps.google.com/?saddr='+start+'&daddr='+end;

  location.href = url;

}


function onError(error)
{
   alert((error.code)

}
</script>
```

If you are working with PhoneGap , you should install InAppBrowser and open url like this.. instead of location.href

```
var ref = window.open(url, 'random_string', 'location=no');
```

### OR

You can also do with...

**HTML**

```
  <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   <div style="width:100%; margin:0px 0px 0 0px; float:left;"> 
     <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:250px; position:relative; bottom:5px;top:5px;"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="restaurant_block_content" id="tGetDirection"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var cur_lat = "";
var cur_lng = ""
var vLatitude = "";
var vLongitude = "";
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var myOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var start = '23.0300, 72.5800';
  var end = '18.9750, 72.8258';

  //var start = cur_lat+","+cur_lng;
  // var end = vLatitude+","+vLongitude;

 var request = {
   origin:start, 
   destination:end,
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);    
  var myRoute = response.routes[0];

  /* instructions */


  var txtDir = '<div><strong>Total Distance : '+myRoute.legs[0].distance.text+'</strong></div><div><strong>Total Duration : '+myRoute.legs[0].duration.text+'</strong></div><ol>';      
  for (var i=0; i<myRoute.legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
    if(myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].maneuver.length > 0)
       maneuver = '<img src="img/'+myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].maneuver+'.png" style="margin-right:10px;width:12px; height:12px;" >'
    else
      maneuver = "";
    txtDir += '<li>'+maneuver+myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].instructions+' <br><strong style="float:right;">'+myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].distance.text+'</strong></li>';
    //alert(myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].maneuver.length)
    //google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].polyline.points)straight
  }
  txtDir += '</ol>';
  document.getElementById('tGetDirection').innerHTML = txtDir;
  $('#tGetDirection').show();

  $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
  }
  });
 }
```